# useRef not grabbing DOM elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to do some animations in our React site. Since we can't use normal DOM methods like getElementByID, I'm trying to access elements with useRef(), which is recommended by a lot of people. But I can't get useRef() to grab anything.

```
 
  const product2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('LOGGING REFS', product2.current);
  }, [product2]);

return (
  <div className='mb-[40px]' ref={product2}>
      <h6 className='font-semibold'>Product 2</h6>
  </div>
```

In the snippet above, the useEffect never fires and nothing is logged to the console. If I try and do something with product2.current in a useEffect, it throws an error because product2 is still null.

Comment: remove [product2] from useEffect and leave it empty [], the useEffect means that component did mount but that useEffect is solely depending on the product2 ref. and remove the `userRef(null)` and leave it only `useRef()` or try initializing it like this: `useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`

Comment: @besjon_c this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in the provided code, [here's my reproduction](https://playcode.io/1761148) and the "LOGGING REFS" is logging correctly.

Few things you could consider -

- Are you exporting and rendering this component correctly? This isn't obvious from the code provided, add some logs at the top of the component to ensure the component is rendering correctly

Regarding your point *"If I try and do something with product2.current in a useEffect, it throws an error because product2 is still null"*.

You would need to add a check for `null` in your `useEffect` before accessing the `current` property, see the updated `useEffect` below

```
    useEffect(() => {
     console.log('LOGGING REFS', product2.current);
     if (product2) {
       // do something 
      }
  }, [product2]);
```

Comment: Well, I commented out a GraphQL query, and now it's working. No idea what the problem is, but I'm not actually using the query data atm so I guess I'll proceed. Thanks

Comment: what sort of log would I use to check that the component is rendering properly?

Comment: A console.log should suffice but in your case if jsx from this component is rendering in the browser then that shouldn't be required. If you're still running into an issue, please update the description to include the surrounding code as the useEffect itself is correct and working.